# WPF: How use MVVM pattern correctly

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Here's a problem that can be solved easily.
My question is how solve it **correctly** if I'd like to adhere to the MVVM pattern.

The model (M) is simple:
It analyses the machine's audio system (Mono or Stereo).
Passes this data to VM
Passes to VM volume level of all (Left/Right or Mono) channels
Gets the selected channel from the user

So, the VM is also quite simple. It holds the following boolean properties:
IsMono - **true** if mono system **false** if stereo
IsLeft - Relevant for stereo only
Also, there are 3 integer properties: RightLevel, LeftLevel and MonoLevel

The V will look like this (for Stereo):
[image]

Now, If the system is Mono then the Audio Channel frame box should not be displayed and the Audio Level frame box should display a single row, labeled "Mono". The source of the level meter will be MonoLevel.
The logic seems to be straightforward, but where do I implement it? I need to bind the IsVisible of frame box "Audio Channel" and other controls to "not IsMono", to bind the mono level meter to "IsMono". There are other (simple) logic that I need to add such as correct labeling and icon.

Should I use Convertors as my main tool? Are convertors considered to be a part of the View (V) or the VM? Should I create (in XAML) a separate view for Mono and Stereo and just make the selected one visible? Is it a good idea to extend the VM to include IsStereo (which is nothing but NOT IsMono) and other redundancies to simplify the XAML?

Comment: Models hold data.  ViewModel is the gateway to your audio logic.  Current state is exposed by properties of the view model, which may include Models you design or primitive/fx types.  The View decides how to display this state information to the user.  User interaction is converted by the view into commands or method calls in the view model.  That's the big picture.

Comment: Thank you Will. You refer to the part of my question that deals with user input. Why not use events? I personally don't like them as they tend to mix VM with V implementation. Do you agree?

Comment: "Why not use events?" Not sure what you're asking.  A ViewModel typically either has DependencyProperties or implements INotifyPropertyChanged, both of which use events (of one kind or another) to which bindings subscribe.  That's how the UI knows to update when the VM's state changes.  Same goes for Models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create on property in the `ViewModel` either `IsStereo`, or `IsMono` because the `ViewModel` shouldn't care about the presentation, hence, one boolean to report its state is enough. Then use 2 converters in the View (they do belong in presentation layer) `BooleanToVisibility` which is provided by the System, and `BooleanToVisiblityNot`, which is exactly reverse, creating one shouldn't be an issue. Binding will trigger on just that one property with a converter will do:

```
<AudioLevelUserControl x:Name="Mono" Visibility="{Binding IsMono, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}"/>
<AudioLevelUserControl x:Name="Stereo" Visibility="{Binding IsMono, Converter={STaticResource BoolToVisNot}"/>
```

Similar logic goes for the rest of the stuff : left, right, etc..

Yet, having both properties in the `ViewModel` is not a "sin" either - just styling/typing preferences. Just gotta make sure that change to one of the properties raises the property changed even of the other, so both bindings re-queries the state() ask for getter for the current value.

```
public bool IsMono
{
    get {return _isMono;}
    set
    {
        if (_isMono == value) return;
        _isMono = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(()=> IsMono);
        RaisePropertyChanged(()=> IsStereo);
}
//then do the same thing for IsStereo property..
```

your question about:

*Now, If the system is Mono then the Audio Channel frame box should not be displayed and the Audio Level frame box should display a single row, labeled "Mono". The source of the level meter will be MonoLevel.*

That is completely up to you and your users. It has nothing to do with MVVVM. There are different schools of thought on the UI design. However, more and more you see everywhere that the general gist is not to overcrowd UI with controls that are of no use at the moment. If you are playing Mono, why use stereo options? Yet, if your users are used to having both - then put both, customer's always right :)

Comment: It seems that from pure architectural pov it is a "sin" as having both is illogical, unless you are aware of the fact that it greatly simplifies the XAML part - which you shouldn't be. On the other hand, converters are really awkward, especially if they are multi-parameter which they frequently are.

Comment: agreed! to add to your points: 1.Having one property in a ViewModel means less tests and bugs to worry about. 2. Even through converters can seem awkward, you can UnitTest them which adds more coverage for UI testing.